# FuelPhp Framework: can't find Casset class

Tags: php, fuelphp

I got this problem when I use FuelPhp framework. And the project wasn't initially developed by me.
Here is the code:

```
foreach (array(
        'reset.css', 
        'jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css',
        'imgareaselect-default.css',
        'select2.css',
        'colorpick.css',
        'master.css'
    ) as $c) { Casset::css($c); }
```

And the error log

> ErrorException [ Error ]: Class 'Casset' not found
>   APPPATH/classesPKGPATH/controllerPKGPATH/base.php @ line 238

Backtrace

> Warning: include(\casset\bootstrap.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in COREPATH/classesPKGPATH/fuel.php @ line 403
>   Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '\casset\bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in COREPATH/classesPKGPATH/fuel.php @ line 403

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your error it seems that your application isn't able to find **APPPATH** and **PKGPATH**. They should be defined in the */public/index.php* file.

This is my configuration:

```
/**
 * Website document root
 */
define('DOCROOT', __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Path to the application directory.
 */
define('APPPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../fuel/app/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Path to the default packages directory.
 */
define('PKGPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../fuel/packages/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```